# How to split the page between charts and data table ?? , Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Example link: [`Link Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/teeraphongsing/5940ku6r/3/)

---

I want to paginate charts and data tables. If there is too much information.
 The problem of this example is in drilldown football-player  and problem output [`Picture`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ht8A.png) .
This the style I want [image: picture]

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to provide the overflow of the graph to be fully displayed and the table of data to be displayed on the next page. like doing 2 pages One page shows the graph data, the other shows a data table.

Comment: I see and where is the problem?

Comment: The problem with the picture is that it can't show all the data because there is a lot of data causing the data table to not show all the data. I want to show all the data whether it is a graph or a data table by having the first page showing the data of the graph and the other data table. Show on the next page so that all information can be displayed.

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible from regular API options and requires custom changes in the core. Have you considered exporting the table as a separate HTML element?